# How to get Uri from Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, uri

Have seen many answers for my question but the problem is they are not in the way i wanted...
For example, I used this answer which is up voted a lot.

```
public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {

          ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

          inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);


          String path = Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);

          return Uri.parse(path);

      }

 private void DoCropAndsetAsWallpaper() {

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, CropWallpaper.class);

            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, getImageUri(FullScreenImgViewPagerActivity.this, mViewPager.getCurrentBitmap()));

            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_CROP_IMAGE);
        }
```

This code works fine and I have no trouble with it.  The problem I have with this is that it inserts the image into the phone and gets the Uri, which i don't want!  So is there any other method that can get Uri of a bitmap without saving it to the phone?

Comment: can u clearly post ur question

Comment: Where's the Bitmap created from? Where do you want the Uri to point to? If you fetch it remotely then use that Uri, otherwise you'll have to save it to the device in order to get a Uri for it.

Comment: @darnmason - 1) let me say tht em using the image loader in which based on the query it loads the images from google ... so the image loader directly loads the image to the View(em using ViewPager) so from tht view em get the bitmap ... 2) Function which em using to share those images required the Uri .. So i need the Uri of the bitmap which is on the view...Think i have made ma question clear to a level...